# Retrieve data from DataList

Tags: asp.net, datalist

It would be a simple table on the page, which has some initial cells and another user should enter.
I use DataList with ItemTemplate:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="CellTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Cell") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

In code i override DataBind() of this control:

```
public override void DataBind()
        {
            MyDataList.DataSource = dataTable;
            MyDataList.DataBind();
        }
```

Now it doesn't work. User enter some cells and click submit button, but dataTable (in the method which handels this button OnClick event) doesn't contains user's data - just only initial. What should I do?

Comment: hi, maybe I'm wrong but shouldn't be using Eval("Cell") instead of Bind("Cell") if you want to display that binded value?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely understand but I think you might be having a problem because you need to check for a post back on the page load. You might want to try something like this:

```
public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!this.IsPostBack)
  {
    myDataList.DataSource = myManager.GetDataTable();
    myDataList.DataBind();
  }
}
```

That way, the data will only be bound to the control on the intial page load and not subsequent post back requests. Page_ Load will be called on each request, and that means and code in your Page_Load will execute before your button click method. Therefore you need to check the IsPostBack property on your page to see if the current request is a post back. If it is, then don't bind your data to your control because you'll lose what the user has entered.

Comment: Sorry, i get too little inforamation. There are the details

Comment: I doubt if controls in ItemTemplate (not EditItemTemplate) could use #Bind and could retrieve user entered data

Comment: It looks like because of using Session/ In debug mode the Table get from Session state. But how should i hadle this?